# "Making VGG-style convNets Great Again" - Reparam section unclear

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have been reading the article: [RepVGG: Making VGG-style Convnet Great Again](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.03697.pdf)

I have reached the section 3.3 **Reparam for plain Inference model**
and it's unclear for me.I have read this section dozen times, and still haven't got it :/
Can somebody please explain and break it into simple steps, how this is done?

I have added the illustration taken form this section.

Thank you!

[image]